# C++: I want to copy/store data from struct into individual arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I wrote a basic get function that takes the elements of a struct, and copies/stores them into separate variables. I want to do the same thing, except to store an array of structs into array variables (the key thing is that I want to use the get function that I already wrote). I can easily do what I want to do without embedding my first function, but I am required to use my first function in the second, and am having some problems.

One of my errors is that there isn't a matching function call in the embedded get function that I put inside my second function (I thought that I matched up the variables correctly with my first get function (i.e. n, c, a, and x)).

Thanks for looking.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib> 

using namespace std; 

struct ABC
{ 
    int n; 
    char c; 
    double a[3]; 
}; 


void get( int & n, char & c, double a[3], const ABC & x )
{ 
    n = x.n; 
    c = x.c; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
    a[i] = x.a[i]; 

    } 
} 

void get( int n[], char c[], double a[][3], const ABC x[], int elements )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++){ 

    get(n, c, a, x); 

    } 

} 

int main()
{ 

    ABC x = {number, m, {1, 2, 3}}; 

    ABC xx[4] = { 

    {123, 'A', {1.1, 1.2, 1.3}}, 
    {234, 'B', {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}}, 
    {345, 'C', {3.1, 3.2, 3.3}}, 
    {456, 'D', {4.1, 4.2, 4.3}} 

    }; 

    int n; 
    char c; 
    int a[] = {}; 

    int n1 [4] = {}; 
    char c1 [4] = {}; 
    double a3 [4] [3] = {}; 

    int elements = 3; 

    get(n1, c1, a3, xx, elements); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Some indentation would be nice.

Comment: The title reminds me of [XY-problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) immediately. So: Why?

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to say

```
get(n[i], c[i], a[i], x[i]);
```

This is not answering your XY-problem though

"fixed" code (to compile) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b423acfed6bf28)**

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I forgot to just add the index to each of the parameters. Lots of HW, so it probably just slipped the mind.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in your get functions with the arrays you're always storing the values into the same place in each array.
You should probably be doing something like:

get(n[i], c[i], a[i], x[i] );